# Menu setting not visibile for other roles on Node Form

Tags: 8, navigation

In Drupal 8 I am creating Editor role with limited access, but the Editor cannot see "Menu Settings" while creating or editing content, this would be helpful when Editor add the node to the menu while creating node. I checked the permission and I can't see any option to turn on Menu Settings for the Editor role or for other roles.

Comment: When you say "Menu Setting" are you referring to the toolbar?`/admin/people/permissions#module-toolbar` . Or is this a menu block that you have created?

Comment: Hi I am referring to the Menu Settings appears on the Node Form, please see the link https://ibb.co/VV91qm4

Answer (score 1):

Go to /admin/people/permissions and make sure the 'administer menu settings' are set for the Editor role.
But I think it is better to install the [Menu Admin per Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_admin_per_menu) module. With this module you make sure the Editor only gets access to certain menu's.

> Menu Admin per Menu allows to give roles per menu admin permissions without giving them full admin permission.

> For instance, you may let certain users manage the items of the Main or Navigation menus but not those of the Management menu.

Comment: Hi, I set the 'administer menu settings' permission for the editor role, still the "Menu settings not showing up on the node form. Please see the attach link to see what I am referring too. https://ibb.co/VV91qm4                                                                                                                                Thank you.

Comment: Then I think you need to select a menu in "menu settings" of your node type. f.e. /admin/structure/types/manage/page

Comment: It shows up when you login as a Administrator but its not showing for other roles.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @StefVanLooveren, works like a charm for me :)